# Unable to play H.264 RTP stream in Android

Tags: android, video-streaming, h.264, rtsp, rtp

I'm currently trying to get my Android playing a H.264 encoded video stream. I pass the URI of my *RTSP* server (and the respective media layer) to a `VideoView` instance and in *Wireshark*, I see the following:

```
Sauce           Destination      Protocol    Info
192.168.1.104   192.168.1.91     RTSP        DESCRIBE rtsp://192.168.1.91:554/mytransmitteroutput1

192.168.1.91    192.168.1.104    RTSP        Reply: RTSP/1.0 200 OK [SDP]
```

Funny thing is, the media player never gets further than this, never calling a **SETUP** etc. It just stops, on the `VideoView` *"Can't play this video"* appears and in Eclipse, I see the generic error `Error (1, -247483648)` so I assume the Android media player isn't happy with the SDP I'm sending back after the **DESCRIBE**. However, players like VLC or MXPlayer are completely satisfied and able to decode the stream.

**Media format parameters in SDP**

fmtp:96 profile-level-id=42C016; packetization-mode=1; sprop-parameter-sets=Z0KAHpZSgWh7IA==,aMkjUg==

[image: Wireshark trace]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm stupid. H.264 was encoded using high profile. According to this page https://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html, Android only supports the base profile.

Comment: How did you ensure that your stream is H264 high profile? I have the same problem, i am trying to play stream from my ip camera. On ip camera configuration, it says the stream is H264. But i dont know if it is base profile or high profile. is there any way to detect it?

Comment: late comment, but maybe helpful for some... you can figure this out from SPS, second byte. if you do have `profile-level-id` - its second-fourth byte of SPS. and `42` means Baseline